# Cross Platform SWF Playback with Python?

Tags: python, cross-platform, flash, wxpython

I'm looking for different solutions to playing back SWF files on Windows, OSX and Linux using Python.  Ideally I'd like to embed the player inside a wxPython frame/window.

One possibility I'm investigating is the Mozilla XPCOM framework since its used by FireFox to load the Flash plugin within the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered [Adobe AIR](http://www.onflex.org/ted/2008/02/why-adobe-air.php)?

Bruce Eckel said: [Try combining the power of Python with the polish of Adobe Flash to create a desktop application.](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208528)

Comment: The url in my edit seems correct to me since it's summary starts with "Combine the power of Python with the polish of Flash to create a desktop application."

Answer (score 2):

Though I don't know how to embed a browser within a wxPython window, the following code might serve in a pinch (and will work cross-platform, assuming you're working in Python 2.5 or above):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(your_swf_url)
```

It might be best to delegate this task to the browser anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do you know of any examples online that show this implemented?